# Should I place my enum out or inside of my int main()?

Tags: c++, enums, program-entry-point

My code works, altough I have a feeling that it could be improved, especially my enum which is currently inside the `main()` function.

I've tried placing my enum outside of the `int main` function, it still works, I personally think it wouldn't be very presentable.

### bookPicker.cpp

```
int main()
{

enum element {
    ICE, FIRE, EARTH, WIND, NONE
};

..The rest of the code..

   return 0;

}
```

Any tips would be much appreciated.

reference to [C++ How to translate my code to OOP with classes and functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54306020/c-how-to-translate-my-code-to-oop-with-classes-and-functions)

Comment: My preference: keep everything scoped as tightly as possible. If no one outside main needs the `enum`, don't let them see it

Comment: Keep is simple! If you need enum outside main() put it outside, if you need it only inside main() then leave it inside.

Comment: @Matthieu Brucher That sounds logical, thank you for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside. You will want to use this enum for a class, the class may be defined someplace else, requiring the enum. So it should be outside.

Also, maybe better to use an enum class in modern C++.

Comment: *You will want to use this enum for a class* Why?  All of the OP's code that uses the `enum` is in `main` so it makes no difference.  Since enum names go in the scope the enum is declared in it should be in the narrowest scope it can be in to avoid polluting the broader scopes with names they don't need.

Comment: It's a book picker.cpp, it's going to evolve. Especially if everything is currently in main!